# Unsuccessful verifying (C# .NET HMACSHA256 Class)

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, hmac, hmacsha1

I'm trying to learn the .NET API and I created a program that compares the key in the source file with a key from an XML file.

I used the following exaple (the third method for varifying a document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=netframework-4.7.1

Right now my program runs but it always says that the files have been tampered with even though I am absolutely sure that they are not since I have just created them.

Here is my code:

VerifyDocument.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class VerifyDocument
{

public static void Main(string[] args)
{

XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(byte[]));
byte[] key;
string keyFile = args[1];
string sourceFile = args[0];
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(keyFile)) {
  key = (byte[]) xml.Deserialize(reader);
}

bool err = false;

        using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key)) // Initialize the keyed hash object.
        {

            byte[] storedHash = new byte[hmac.HashSize / 8]; // Create an array to hold the keyed hash value read from the file.

            using (FileStream inStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open)) // Create a FileStream for the source file.
            {

                inStream.Read(storedHash, 0, storedHash.Length); // Read in the storedHash.

                byte[] computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(inStream);
                // compare the computed hash with the stored value

                for (int i = 0; i < storedHash.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (computedHash[i] != storedHash[i])
                    {
                        err = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hash values differ! Signed file has been tampered with!");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hash values agree -- no tampering occurred.");

        }

}

}
```

SignDocument.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class HMACSHA256example
{    

   public static void Main(string[] args)
  {


    if (args.Length != 2) {
      Console.WriteLine("Usage: [mono] SignDocument.exe <filename> <key>");
      Environment.Exit(1);
    } else
    {
      XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(byte[]));
      byte[] key;
      string keyFile = args[1];
      string sourceFile = args[0];
      string destFile = sourceFile + ".hash";
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(keyFile)) {
        key = (byte[]) xml.Deserialize(reader);
      }

      using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key)) // Initialize the keyed hash object.
      {
          using (FileStream inStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open))
          {
              using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(destFile, FileMode.Create))
              {

                  byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(inStream); // Compute the hash of the input file.


                  outStream.Write(hashValue, 0, hashValue.Length); // Write the computed hash value to the output file.

          }
      }

    }

 }
 }
 }
```

CreateKey.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace COMP3911.Crypto {


class CreateKey {
static void Main(string[] args) {

  string input;

  if (args.Length == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Usage: [mono] CreateKey.exe <filename>");
    Environment.Exit(1);
  }

  byte[] secretkey = new Byte[64];
        //RNGCryptoServiceProvider is an implementation of a random number generator.
        using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            // The array is now filled with cryptographically strong random bytes.
            rng.GetBytes(secretkey);
        }


  // XML
  string keyfile = args[0] + ".key";
  using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(keyfile, false)) {
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(byte[]));
    xml.Serialize(output, secretkey);
  }
}
}

}
```

ANY HELP would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Is not a real question. Please read [ask] and edit your question to have a proper title

Comment: You'll need to share how you created the file that you're checking. The code you've shared looks reasonable, assuming the file you're checking is formatted the way the code expects (the beginning of the file is an HMAC-SHA256 of the rest of the file).

Comment: Hi smarx. I have just shared the 3 small programs I'm using, including the one that generates an XML key and computes HMAC for the contents of a
specified file.

Answer (score 0):

Your "sign" program reads `inStream` and writes just the HMAC to `outStream`.

Your "verify" program reads a file and expects that it is the HMAC followed by the data.

Either "sign" needs to rewind `inStream` and then copy it into `outStream` or you need to change "verify" to look at the two files independently.

Answer (score 0):

`SignDocument.cs` has the error. You're writing the signature but failing to write the rest of the file.

It should be something like this (mostly copied from the documentation page you linked to):

```
using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key)) // Initialize the keyed hash object.
{
    using (FileStream inStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(destFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(inStream); // Compute the hash of the input file.
            outStream.Write(hashValue, 0, hashValue.Length); // Write the computed hash value to the output file.

            inStream.Position = 0;
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            do
            {
                bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead > 0);

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Not sure why the MSDN version doesn't use `CopyTo`, but seems better:

```
byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(inStream);
outStream.Write(hashValue, 0, hashValue.Length);

inStream.Position = 0;
inStream.CopyTo(outStream);
```